# an issue with axios using Laravel 5.4 can't understand

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I've an issue that cant understand,
I'm trying to send axios post requests using Vuejs to Laravel,
as is they describe :

1. install the axios package.
2. add the token to the header (by default is added in bootstrap).

---

my issue when i send the post request

the first is done but if i will send another one it gives me the

```
TokenMismatchException
```

---

please help me

the code in my vue file

```
login() {
    this.userNotExiste = null;
    var app = this
    axios.post('/user/login', {email: this.email, password: this.password})
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.userConnected) {
                app.userConnected = response.data.userConnected;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = window.location;
                }, 1000);
            }

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                if (!_.isEmpty(error.response.data))
                    if (!_.isEmpty(error.response.data.messages)) {
                        if (!_.isEmpty(error.response.data.messages.email))  app.loginErrors.email = error.response.data.messages.email[0]
                        if (!_.isEmpty(error.response.data.messages.password)) app.loginErrors.password = error.response.data.messages.password[0]
                    }

                if (!_.isEmpty(error.response.data.userNotExiste)) app.userNotExiste = error.response.data.userNotExiste

            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log(error.request)
            } else {
                console.log('Contact : contact@33sprog.com')
            }
        })
}
```

in my laravel section

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ], [
        'email.email'       => 'Entrer adresse email correct',
        'email.required'    => 'Veuillez saisir une adresse email',
        'password.required' => 'Veillez saisir votre mot de passe',
    ]);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'messages' => $validation->messages(),
        ], 400);
    }

    $user = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);

    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'userNotExiste' => 'Adresse email ou mot de passe incorrecte',
        ], 400);
    }

    return response()->json(['userConnected' => 'Vous etes bien connecte'], 200);
}
```

at my php file

### at my bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

---

Thanks for helping

Comment: You're only attached the header to the `window.axios` yet in your file you're using `axios` as if you've loaded the module again, which will not have the header applied to it.

Comment: So how can i resolve this please

Comment: Well, I would start by trying to use `window.axios` instead of `axios`. in the post request. Does that fix it?

Comment: Oww no! still got teh same problem

Comment: edit : in ```app\http\middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php``` file  ```protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];``` and test it

Comment: Thanks @Mohammadb, but i guess the application will not be secure against the CSRF ? is that true

Comment: @K.33s Indeed. That's why this solution isn't the best way to deal with the problem!

Comment: @K.33s Have you included the csrf-token in your meta-data? Otherwise, the JS cannot fetch it of course :D

Comment: @manniL Yes you're right,

Comment: @manniL yeah i put it on <meta .. content, but not working,
it works but for example if i continue clicking many time the submit button for over more than 10 or 20 posts request, the error show up